# How to grab the username in the JSON Twitter V2 response using PHP?

Tags: php, json, twitter

I can grab "text" for example with the code below, but how can I grab the username "Lionek_Gaming" under includes > user ?

```
$tweets = json_decode($response);

foreach($tweets->data as $tweet) {

$text = $tweet->text;

echo $text;

}
```

**Json response**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "author_id": "1169144412171055104",
            "id": "1386731275160072192",
            "text": "sell Bitcoin at sweet rates"
        }
 
    ],
    "includes": {
        "users": [

            {
                "id": "1304731585112158209",
                "name": "Lionek_official #BRG",
                "username": "Lionek_Gaming"
            }
        ]
    },

}
```

Comment: Maybe use the authorId to query the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
foreach($tweets->includes->users as $user) {
    $username = $user->username;
    echo $username;
}
```